# FIFO queue with circular list

Tags: java, stack, queue

I have created a queue implementation using a single connection list.In this code I am using 2 pointers (first,last) to define the start and the end of my queue. My code is :

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.*
/**
* @author Justin Bieber
*/
public class StringQueueImpl<T> implements StringQueue {

private int total;         // number of elements on queue
private Node head;    // beginning of queue
private Node tail;     // end of queue

private class Node {
    T ele;
    Node next;
    Node(T ele) {
    this.ele = ele;
    next = null; } 
} 
 /**
 * Creates an empty queue.
 */
public StringQueueImpl() {
    first = null;
    last  = null;
    total = 0;
}

boolean isEmpty() {
    return (head == null); 
}

public <T> void put(T ele) {
    Node t = tail;
    tail = new Node(ele);
    if (isEmpty()) head = tail;
    else t.next = tail; 
    total++;
} 

public T get() {
    if (isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
    T v = head.ele;
    Node t = head.next;
    head = t;
    return v; 
    total--;
} 


public T peek() {
    if (isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
    return head.ele;
}

Node node = head; 
public void printQueue(PrintStream stream){
    while(node != null){
        stream.println(node.ele);
        stream.flush();
        node = node.next;
    }
}    
public int size(){
    return total;
}
}
```

My question is how can I create a queue implementation using a circular list. (Instead of 2 pointers for the start and the end I would like to use only one pointer wich will be used for both the start and the end of the queue).

Any help is apreciated . Thank you